Create an S3 blobstore on Nexus fails ("The S3 bucket exists but you are not the owner")
Before  mentioning my problem, I  want to inform you that I'm using terraform and having nexus container  running on EC2 orchestrated by Amazon ECS. Here  is the objective: I want to create an S3 blobstore on nexus.I created a  task  definition and I added the correct execution and task role to make nexus work  properly at first. When I created  the S3 blobstore I got the problem that "The S3 bucket exists but you are not the owner". When I faced  this problem  I tried  to make the optional authentication like mentioned by Sonatype .I created an IAM user and gave it S3FullAccess Permissions.I created credentials .I associated this IAM user to the target S3 bucket like this code is showing.
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "nexus_s3_blobstore_policy_document" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:DeleteObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
      "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
      "s3:PutObjectTagging",
      "s3:GetObjectTagging",
      "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
      "s3:GetBucketAcl"
    ]
    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.nexus_repo.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.nexus_repo.arn}/*"
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_iam_user.s3_blobstore_access_user.arn]
    }

  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "blob_store_rules" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.nexus_repo.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.nexus_s3_blobstore_policy_document.json
}  

This worked fine  for me and  I manged to create the S3-blobstore.Now I don't want to use this optional authentication.Some experts recommended me  to add iam policies to access S3 bucket and attach them to the execution role associated to the task definition to avoid  the authentication. Here  is my added policies and their attachment with terraform.I may be   using so many wrong useless code. I don't know  if there is an error in the code or  the solution itself is wrong.
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_task_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole",

    ]
    effect = "Allow"


    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "nexus_s3_access_policy_document" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "s3:DeleteBucket",
      "s3:CreateBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.nexus_repo.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.nexus_repo.arn}/*"
    ]

  }
}

/*IAM  document    policy   for  S3 */

resource "aws_iam_policy" "s3_bucket_policy" {
  name   = "s3BucketPolicy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.nexus_s3_access_policy_document.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_role" {
  name               = "ecs-task-role-${local.name_suffix}"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_doc.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_exec_role" {
  name               = "ecs-exec-role-${local.name_suffix}"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_task_doc.json

}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_exec_role_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

/*Attachment task role with s3  */

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_task_s3_attachement" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_bucket_policy.arn

}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_s3_role_exec_attachement" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_bucket_policy.arn
}

